# Braintree submit for settlement in sandbox

Tags: node.js, braintree

I created a simple testscript in NodeJS for creating transactions with the Braintree SDK. However, whenever I try to use a fake failing nonce, it just succeeds. I am sure I am missing something simple here, but I can not figure out what it is.

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: 10,
    paymentMethodNonce: "fake-processor-declined-mastercard-nonce",
    options: {
        submitForSettlement: true
    }
}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, "\t"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

The `fake-processor-declined` nonces don't simulate failed transactions, but failed credit card verifications. Enable card verification in the Braintree control panel by going to Settings > Processing > Card Verification. Then, make your options hash look like this:
 ​

```
  options: {
    submitForSettlement: true,
    verifyCard: true
  }
```

​
The transaction will no longer succeed and will return an authorization error.
​

If you are trying to simulate a failed transaction, use a specific [test transaction amount](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/node#test-amounts) with `fake-valid-nonce` instead.

If you have any additional questions, feel free to reach out to [Braintree support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com).

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies a lot! I will give it a try soon.

Comment: I thought the verifyCard boolean was only for storing creditcards in vault using ```paymentMethod.create()```